# Calling same function multiple times with different arguments jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am dynamically creating html elements like this

`<a href="javascript:scheduleInterview('+titleObj.id+','+titleObj.profile_id+')" style="text-decoration: none;"><li>&nbsp;&nbsp;Schedule</li></a>`,

`titleObj.id and titleObj.profile_id`  are data from ajax response

The created elements will look like the below one.

```
<a href="javascript:scheduleInterview(15,22)" style="text-decoration: none;"><li>&nbsp;&nbsp;Schedule</li></a>
```

The above anchor tag calls scheduleInterview(id,profile_id).

scheduleInterview() gets the parameters and stores it to pass to ajax function and open a modal(has a form) to get more form input values which will also be passed to the same ajax function along with the parameters value. Now the issue is,  modal form action is set to the same function scheduleInterview() cause i need both parameters and form input values.

```
function scheduleInterview(id,profile_id){
    console.log("The student id is "+id);
    console.log("the profile id is "+profile_id);

        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    var candidate_id = id;
    var profile_id = profile_id;
    var inter_name = $('#inter_name').val();
    var date = $('#inter_date').val();
    var time = $('#inter_hr').val();
    var meridian = $('#inter_mr').val();
    candidate_id = $("#m_can_id").val();
    profile_id = $("#m_can_p_id").val();

    var dataString = 'inter_name='  +inter_name+ '&inter_date='  +date+ '&inter_time='  +time+ '&inter_meridian='  +meridian+ '&candidate_id=' +candidate_id+ '&profile_id=' +profile_id;

    console.log(dataString);
    $.ajax({


    })
}
```

The above method log the id and profile_id as 15 and 22 exactly. After that it opens the modal which has a form whose action points to the same function but without parameters.

```
<form action ="javascript:scheduleInterview()" method= "post" id = "sche_inter_form">

</form>
```

So it overrides parameters value to undefined. But I need the parameters value along with the form input values of the modal. I really don't know how to go about this. Finally after modal submission i have dataString value like this

```
inter_name=Jonathan&inter_date=12/06/1995&inter_time=02:30&inter_meridian=AM&candidate_id=undefined&profile_id=undefined
```

Comment: Don't do this: `action ="javascript:scheduleInterview()"` instead, listen to the form submit event.

Comment: And the link click event - like this: `'<a class="sceduleLink"  href="#" data-id="'+titleObj.id+'" data-profile-id="'+titleObj.profile_id+'" style="text-decoration: none;"><li>&nbsp;&nbsp;Schedule</li></a>`

Comment: why are you replace candidate_id  and user id?

Comment: @evolutionxbox if i use form submit event , then what will i use in form action ?

Comment: Nothing. It's not required.

Comment: Don't want to trow you off, but you're trying the whole thing in a strange way. First, don't redefine variables, makes no sense, second, don't ever try to run a JS function that requires parameters, without them, best case scenario you'll get a warning.
My advice, try to rethink the whole process and what are you trying to achive, I know, I've been there. 
And if you really need it that way, try to use the callback function on AJAX, to get what you want.